# Ubuntu 20.04 disable touch gestures

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, gestures

I would like an application to run 24/7. It's an interactive application that uses a touch panel.

Customers keep killing the application by swiping up with 2-3 fingers or more.

Is there any way of disabling the gestures?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Disable Gestures](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1140/disable-gestures/)  extension using either Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: That extension doesn't seem to do anything. :(

Comment: install this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep

then install the above extension

Comment: I already have that installed. (As well as the firefox equivalent.) The extension installs just fine and shows up in the extensions list. It just doesn't seem to...do anything.